# Vbs - List all visible windows script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to list all visible windows (the name and the top).
My script is working well but it need Microsoft Word installation. 
To execute my script you can run this command

```
Cscript -B myScript.vbs
```

muScript.vbs :

```
Dim console
Set console = WScript.StdOut
Dim myString
myString = ""

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks
Set colTasks = Word.Tasks
For Each Task in Tasks
    If Task.Visible Then 
        If colTasks.Exists(Task.Name) Then
            myString = myString & "@@##@@" & colTasks(Task.Name).Name & ","& colTasks(Task.Name).Top
        End If  
   End If
Next
Word.Quit
console.WriteLine myString
```

Do you know how I can list visible windows like myScript.vbs without Microsoft Word installation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: u can use **tasklist** command(WScript Shell Exec) to list and filter processes by name / windowtitle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. However you can list all of the running processes.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process.htm

```
' Process.vbs
' VBScript Win32_Process to discover which processes are running
' Author Guy Thomas http://computerperformance.co.uk/
' Version 1.4 - December 2010
' -------------------------------------------------------' 
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strList

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
  strList = strList & vbCr & _
  objProcess.Name
Next

WSCript.Echo strList
WScript.Quit

' End of List Process Example VBScript
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but with your script, I can't list opened windows (position and name). Could you help me?

Comment: As per my first comment. It's not possible.